# Log4j2 logging of classes in tomcat's shared classpath

Tags: java, tomcat7, log4j2

I have a webapp with it's own classes under its WEB-INF folder, which is using log4j2 for logging. I configured it with log4j2-web and can see logs from those classes. So far so good.

I am wrecking my brain, however, getting to see logs from libs (jars) that are defined in the **common**/**shared** classpath of tomcat. A jar (one for example) I am trying, is using log4j2 api too for logging.

Note that only when I move the jar from the common classpath to lib folder under the webapp's WEB-INF it does show logs. Meaning the configuration file is fine regarding appender and logger names...

Is there something I'm missing or this is how log4j2 works?
I am using Tomcat 7
Log4j2 2.11.0

Any help would be welcomed! Thanks.

The (simplified) log4j2.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
<Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="sample.appender" fileName="server.log"
                 filePattern="server.log.%i.gz" bufferedIO="false" bufferSize="0">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d [%t] (%F:%L) %-5p - %m%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="5242880"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="13"/>
    </RollingFile>
</Appenders>

<Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.my.server" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="sample.appender"/>
    </Logger>

    <Logger name="com.3rd.party.sample" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <AppenderRef ref="sample.appender"/>
    </Logger>

    <Root level="FATAL"/>
</Loggers>
```

Comment: Can you post your Log4J `2.x` config file and some of the logging statements that you also see?

Comment: I would configure the `sample.appender` inside the `Root` element, like [this one](https://bitbucket.org/vadimvera/java-spring-struts2/src/1a03367efcd71191a092e0cbc1528bbeec52ff60/src/main/resources/log4j2.xml?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default). I think the way you have it, no libraries are going to be able to log anything to `server.log` at all since there is no appender that points to that — so everything will be thrown in the console by using their logging library.

Comment: Thanks. but no luck.
It seems like a classpath issue, since as mentioned moving the lib inside the webapp works...

Comment: And also after trying, moving my own server classes into a jar and putting it in common classpath disables ALL logs... :(